# Django - INSTALLED_APPS for submodule

Tags: python, django

I created an app called API using `django startapp api`. I then loaded this app from my main application (`app`) in the settings.py (`app/settings.py`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'api.apps.ApiConfig',
   ...
]
```

This works great! Then, I created a settings.py file in the api folder (`api/settings.py`). I would like to load a module called `rest_framework` from within this submodule (due to reusability). So the `api/settings.py` file contains the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'rest_framework'
]
```

The `rest_framework` module, however, is not loaded when I run the application. I found the following workaround (for `app/settings.py`):

```
from api.settings import INSTALLED_APPS as API_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS += API_APPS
```

I think this is not the best way of loading the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the main application for all submodules. Is there a better way of loading all submodules `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: 2 apps should be entirely independent of each other. Looks like you are mixing dependencies, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Exactly. This is why I asked :-). The `api` app depends on the `rest_framework` and the main application (`app`) depends on the `api` app. So how can I make sure that I don't need to load the `api` dependencies in the `settings.py` of `app`?

Comment: You should document your `api` app in a way that makes it clear that one needs to add both `'api.apps.ApiConfig'` (turrible CamelCase) and `'rest_framework'` in their `INSTALLED_APPS`. There are a lot of reuseable apps and frameworks out there that require more than one app  to be added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` to work properly.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I was just wondering if there was a way of loading submodule dependencies automatically. But there is not a way of doing so?

Comment: Having multiple `settings.py` will only make it worse. Like @schwobaseggl mentioned, you need to specify the settings your `api` app requires in the docs or somewhere that let's the user know that you **can't** do without them.

Comment: @Kevin No, you will find almost all `django` libraries / apps tell you to include things in the settings.py that require them to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One question out of curiosity: why would it be worse to have multiple `settings.py`? Only circular dependencies would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good place for per-app settings is in the `AppConfig` class. The default app config can have sensible defaults, and they can be customised by subclassing the default app config. Most Django apps do not have a `settings.py`, so if you add `app/settings.py` it will look unusual to other Django developers.

Personally, I would avoid trying to do clever things in your app config (or app/settings.py). It is less clear which apps are installed when you look at the project's settings file, and could introduce subtle errors.

The Django debug toolbar, a very popular Django app with many contributions from core Django developers, [removed automatic setup](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#removed-features) in 1.6, because it was 'problematic'.